# ASP.NET Web API Error: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I checked other sulotion sugessions that asked and answered here, but still couldn't find what's wrong with my own code.

I have a '**members**' and '**fals**' (means something like blogpost) controllers. every member has its own multiple '**fals**' records, so I wanted to list '**fals**' belongs to spesific member.

I wanted to add a custom action to my Web API to do this job, here is it:

```
    [HttpGet, ActionName("fals"), Route("members/{id}/fals")]
    public IQueryable<Fal> fals(int id)
    {
        Member member = db.Members.Find(id);
        return member.Fals();
    }
```

So, here is WebApiConfig customization:

```
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}"
        );
```

I know there are two Route, even if I comment or uncomment the second Route it changes nothing.

When I try to call http://localhost:51601/api/members/1/fals URL it says:

```
{
"Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:51601/api/members/1/fals'.",
"MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Members' that matches the name 'fals'."}
```

ID 1 existed, as I pasted the code fals existed, but couldn't figured it out.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you remove the "Route" attribute from the method? e.g. `[HttpGet, ActionName("fals")]`

Comment: Just removed it, and now it looks like working! I though it was required but, realized it's not. Thanks.

Comment: I guess it was overriding the default route, so you'll probably find that if you put the route back, but call it without the `/api/` part of the URL it would have worked too. I wasn't sure whether you were using attribute routing as well, and if you aren't, how the Route attribute interacts with traditional routing, so it was a bit of a guess - I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using attribute routing or not, but try removing the Route attribute from the controller action.

```
[HttpGet, ActionName("fals")]
```

If the route is "interfering" with the conventional routing I expect this would work, or you could also try calling the URL without the /api/ part because that it missing from the Route you have specified in the attribute.